# realm query date type?

Tags: swift, realm

swift, xcode8

I made realm file with csv importer
(https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter/tree/master/RealmConverter)

This is realm file's schema:

```
birthday:string 
name : string
age  : int

class people:object
{
    dynamic var date = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
} 

let temp : people
```

I want to query date field:

```
realm.object(self.people).filter("birthday >= 2016-01-01") // error!
```

If realm file schema's birthday type is string, can I query  >= or between ?
Should I change realm file schema birthday:string -> birthday:NSDate ?

Comment: I would have thought you'd want a date stored as a date, not a string, but nevertheless... Your current filter does not list the date as a string. It should have single quotes around it like `"birthday >= '2016-01-01'"`. However, ">=" possibly does not work with String as described in the documentation - The comparison operators ==, <=, <, >=, >, !=, and BETWEEN are supported for Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, Float, Double and NSDate property types. Such as age == 45

Comment: thanks. reply so.. should i change realm file schema? should i change cocoa converter source?

Comment: One approach would be to have two object properties, one that is stored in the Realm as a Date and one computed String for importing from CSV. The computed property would convert the imported string to a date and store it in the Date property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `>=` operator for strings, see more in [Filtering section in docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering).

You need to use `NSDate` for property type to be able to use comparison operators in queries, but unfortunately RealmConverter doesn't support detection of dates currently. So you'll probably need to import your data manually or implement this feature in RealmConverter and send a pull request :)